# Rails generate model including validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, command-line-arguments, generator, models

I was wondering if anybody knew of a way to do something like the following:

```
rails generate model Foo name:string, validates: {:name, uniqueness: true}
```

That is, whilst declaring a model generator with some attributes, work some rails magic to add your validations at the same time.

Comment: You can't. You can check all the available options for generating a model using `rails g model -h`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I wish I could have chosen more than one answer. The answer I have chosen is purely because it goes into some lower-level concepts that will be useful in a solution I'm currently implementing to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, there isn't currently a way to do this.  Most of the special options for the `rails generate model` command are parsed by the `parse_type_and_options` method in [generated_attribute.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb).  The [model_generator.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb) will then build the model and migration files using this info.

The template for the model file that is created is [model.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/model.rb).  In Rails 4 this template can add in special code for `belongs_to`, `polymorphic`, and `has_secure_password` but not code related to validations.

The template for the migration file that is created is [create_table_migration.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb).  In Rails 4 this can add in special options for `limit`, `decimal`, and `precision`.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't. The rails generate model command is directly tied to database functionality. For example, you should be able to do a command like this rails generate model Foo name:string:uniq. This would force the database to require a unique string for the name. This wouldn't add anything to your foo.rb file.

Here is some more information about rails model generations:
http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/03/generate-rails-migrations-that-automagically-add-your-change/

Answer (score 1):

Since [Rails 3.2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html) it has been possible to pass `:uniq` to the column definition on the rails command line.

The way to do this is relatively simple; just add `:uniq` after the column and type definitions, e.g.:

```
rails generate model Foo name:string:uniq
```